# Large bib entry (>20000 characters)

Tags: bibtex

My bibliography contains a very big paper (3000+ authors).

When trying to cite that paper, I get this error:

```
Your field is more than 20000 characters---line 495 of file research.bib
```

And the citation doesn't appear in the final document.

**Question:**
How do I fix this or bypass that limit?

Comment: D= What paper is this? I'm curious now!

Comment: I think that you would need to recompile BibTeX with a larger memory size or cut some author. Or maybe use biber and BibLaTeX instead...

Comment: Two words: *et al.* :)

Comment: it's the one about gravitational waves produced by colliding neutron stars (http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/2041-8213/aa91c9) :)

Comment: @hdev My field is ocean wave energy, but I'm definitely citing this paper in my master's thesis =D

Comment: The linked `.bib` entry has two ill-formed names. But even fixing those, `biblatex` crashes on the entry, although `biber` seems to process it.

Comment: @AlanMunn I could get the `.bib` file to compile with `biblatex` and Biber after I fixed the indicated comma errors and removed the `abstract` field, which contained unescaped special characters like `#`. But one should not try to run Biber with `uniquename` enabled, figuring out the name disambiguation for 3600 names did go well for Biber on my machine.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Be sure to print all 3600 odd names, in a short test that produced a 15-page bibliography.

Comment: @moewe I hadn't noticed the abstract (BibDesk displays it separately).

Comment: @moewe I think I'll have to use some settings from `savetrees` :P

Answer (score 13):

The BibTeX file exported by IOP is malformed as institutional authors are intermingled with persons and even Biber chokes on it. With some editing it will run, but at the end it will output “B. P. Abbot et al.”.

Change `author=` into `fullauthor=` and add the field

```
author={B. P. Abbot and others},
```

BibTeX will ignore the humongous `fullauthor` field.

Comment: You're right, think I might have to resort to chopping it manually

Comment: @hdev No need to remove the full list, just change the field name to something BibTeX ignores and add a reduced list like I showed.